# VSCode (CSS): List of used colors when write # doesn't appear

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I just updated VSCode (Versión: 1.81.1 (Universal)). Before this update, every time I wrote (when using CSS) "#" the program triggered a list of colors: first the colors used in my code and then the recommendations of the basics. Now that list doesn't appear unless I'm exclusively in a variable that requires to pick a color, and anyway only works when I finish writing the ":". I put some captures to help understanding the issue:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QlH6.png)

Some examples of cases where it worked before:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMJLD.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIZDW.png)

For me it was confortable how it worked before, I'm used to it.
Do you guys know how can I turn it like before?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use the shortcut keys Ctrl+Shift+X and install the "Color Highlight" extension.

Comment: I appreciate your recommendation, but it's not what I'm looking for. I don't have the need to highlight the colors codes (I'm fine with the little square). I'm looking for a way to make the list appear when I write "#" in any part of the code, not only when I put ":" ¡Thanks anyways!